# OMNeT++ : for loop and value assignation in .NED file

Tags: omnet++

I'm a beginner in using the OMNeT++ simulator, sorry in advance if I do something wrong.
I would like to create a network that is randomly disposed, and for that I'm trying to implement a random graph program as a `.ned` file. Here is an example of the code I would like to implement (written in `.c`, only to show you an example) :

```
int nbHost = 10;
double randConnect = 0.6;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int src = 0; src < nbHost-1; src++)
    {
        if (uniform(0,1) < randConnect)
        {
            // set dest different of src
            int dest = uniform(0,nbHost-2);
            if (dest >= src)
                dest++;
            
            //connect src to host
        }
    }
    randConnect -= 0.05;        
}
```

I tried to translate it into a `.ned` file, and got this :

```
simple Node
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=block/routing");
        
    gates:
        inout gate[];
}

network Network
{
    parameters:
        int nbHost = default(10);
        int count = default(10);
        double randConnect = default(0.6);
        int dest;
        
    types:
        channel Channel extends ned.DelayChannel { delay = 100ms; }
        
    submodules:
        host[nbHost]: Node;
        
    connections allowunconnected:
        for i=0..count, for src=0..nbHost-1, if uniform(0,1)<randConnect {
            
            dest = uniform(0,nbHost-2);
            if dest >= src {
                dest++;
            }
            
            host[src].gate++ <--> Channel <--> host[dest].gate++;
        }
        
}
```

But several problems appear and I can't find a solution. First, it seems like I can't assign a value like I want to do with `dest = uniform(0,nbHost-2);`. I don't know if this is the proper way or even possible. Second, the line `if dest >= src {` is not possible like this, because `nested connection groups is not allowed` and I don't know how to manage it. Finally, I can't even find a way to add `randConnect -= 0.05;` on the `.ned` file, due to the way the `for loop` is made.

Any help or tips would be welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve here. I'm confused about the outer loop's (i) goal. Your current code could connect the same nodes several times (as it iterates 10 times on all hosts). My guess is that you want to have 10 different random graph networks each with a different connectedness parameter and then study some behaviour of those networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `.ned` is a declarative language, so it is somewhat limited what you can do with it. Specifically, you cannot have control structures or variable declarations, so translating your C code directly is not the way to go. This is how the problem would be solved in NED:

```
network RandomGraph
{
    parameters:
        int n = default(10);
        double connectedness = 0.6 - (${0..10})*0.05; // 11 runs
    submodules:
        node[n]: RandomGraphNode;
    connections:
        for i = 0..n-2, for j = i+1..n-1 {
            node[i].g++ <--> node[j].g++ if uniform(0,1)<connectedness;
        }
}
```

Note that the `${}` construct in the `connectedness` expression is called *iteration variable* (look in the manual for more info)